# SP2010 - Workflow access denied when user has 'add-only' permissions

Tags: workflow, permissions, access, denied

We have a calendar based approval system in SP 2010, as you add a record, a workflow is triggered that edits a few hidden fields in the background.....

Previously, all users had add/contribute permissions and we never had any issues with the workflows - but we had a problem where they could still edit the calendar entries AFTER they had been approved (which defeats the purpose of having the approval system!) - so, I removed the contribute option from all users so that they can add only - but now we get an 'access denied' error and the workflow cancels itself.

I would try and create it using an 'impersonation step' - but there are about 15 steps, each with about 10 conditions / steps looking at multiple variables, so it'll take a while to re-create - unless, there's a way to run the whole workflow as in impersonation step or migrate existing rules from one step to another?

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to get this working? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you have already listed the two options you have:
- give all workflow users contribute permissions on the list
- use Impersonation Step

Using the Impersonation Step means that you have to recreate your workflow in SPD 2010 as copy & paste is only supported for SPD 2013 workflows.

There is the possibility to export, manipulate and re-import the workflow xoml file, but i would strongly disadvice.

Comment: Thanks for the response, not what I wanted to hear but guess I'll have to go through the process of re-creating the workflow! Thanks for confirming!