# Issues with Impersonation Step (SP2010 workflow) using SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, impersonation, workflow-app-step

I'm using Impersonation Step (in SP2010 workflow) to remove /replace permissions.

But in some instance I get access denied error when I manually run the workflow and also when or when I set it to automatically start when an item is changed.

What permission should I have in the site level to be able to run this successfully? Do I need to be a site collection admin?

Currently I have been added as a site owner with full control.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have access to ULS logs on the SharePoint server? If yes, can you run the workflow manually and check if you get anything about access denied in the logs?

Comment: Thanks but I'm on SharePoint Online

Comment: Does this link give any clues? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159892/sp2010-workflow-access-denied-when-user-has-add-only-permissions

Answer (score 3):

What’s the account who you login SharePoint Designer and create workflow?

SP2010 Workflow Impersonation Step runs the workflow on the credentials of the **Workflow Author**. Please make sure the workflow author has proper permission.

If the issue exists, switch another user account and check again.

Comment: Thats the key point: Impersonation in SP Designer Workflows does not run the step as the System User, but as the Workflow Author (explicitly: the user that last **published** the workflow). 

So if the permissions for the site owner group also get removed from the item (e.g. during replacing permissions), all subsequent actions will fail because the workflow author no longer has the right to set permissions himself. Yes, adding the workflow author to the Site Collection Admins will definitely prevent those issues.

Comment: Thanks guys .I switched my solution to another site collection and it worked.I think you need to be site collection admin to use the impersonation correctly.